# Who is responsible for indexing all of the packages that work with a given package manager?

Tags: apt, package-managers

`apt` lets you search for a package by name, so there must be some sort of indexed database of packages that apt works with.

Who is responsible for making the database of packages that work with a certain package manager (say `apt`). How is this done? Can you trust whoever is making this decision to make sure that the packages do not contain security flaws?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  But it's configurable - see `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a similar file to see where the package lists used by your system are coming from.  Normally it will be a repository set up by the vendor of the particular OS being used.  Obviously no human or organization is infallible so whether you can trust them is up to your own risk analysis.

Comment: Thanks. I know it's not a programming question in the sense that it is not about accomplishing a specific objective through code, but I thought it was something that could apply and help many people, hence why I asked it.

Comment: Sure - but you could ask it on a site where it's more appropriate, such as http://unix.stackexchange.com.  (Where it might already be answered, so search first.)

Comment: I see. I'll keep that in mind.